# product filtering not happening properly when there is space between data attributes of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I searched for some code online regarding product filtering with data attibutes with div.I have two data attributes now one is brand and second one is store.I m filtering the records on the basis of brand and store checkboxes selection.The filtering is appening correctly with given code as below

```
<div id="prod">
<div class="content" data-brand="Andrew" data-price="1000" data-store="JCPenny">Andrew</div><br />
<div class="content" data-brand="Hill" data-price="1200" data-store="JCPenny">Hill</div><br />
<div class="content" data-brand="Andrew" data-price="2000" data-store="JCPenny">Andrew</div><br />
<div class="content" data-brand="Hill" data-price="800" data-store="SuperMart">Hill</div><br />
<div class="content" data-brand="Hill" data-price="1300" data-store="SuperMart">Hill</div><br />
<div class="content" data-brand="Andrew" data-price="800" data-store="JCPenny">Andrew</div><br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="Andrew" />Andrew
    <input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="Hill" />Hill
    <input type="checkbox" class="store" id="JCPenny" />JCPenny
    <input type="checkbox" class="store" id="SuperMart" />SuperMart
</div>


var a=$("input.brand");
    var b=$("input.store");
    var brand=new Array();
    var store=new Array();
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
       $('#prod >div').hide();
       if(this.className == "brand"){
           console.debug("brand checked");
           brand.push($(this).attr('id'));
        }else if(this.className == "store"){
           console.debug("store checked");
           store.push($(this).attr('id'));
        }
         console.log(brand+","+store);
         displaydivs(brand,store);
    }else{
     $('#prod >div').show();
     if(this.className == "brand"){
         var index = brand.indexOf($(this).attr('id'));
         if (index > -1) {
            brand.splice(index, 1);
         }       
     }else if(this.className == "store"){
         var index = store.indexOf($(this).attr('id'));
         if (index > -1) {
            store.splice(index, 1);
         } 
     }
     displaydivs(brand,store);
    }     
});


    function displaydivs(brand,store)
    {
        $("#prod >div").hide();
    if(brand.length > 0 & store.length > 0){ 
        $.each(brand, function( index, value ){
            var temp = $("#prod >div[data-brand="+value+"]")[0];
            var data = $(temp).attr("data-store");
            var idx = store.indexOf(data);
            if(idx > -1){
              $("#prod >div[data-brand="+value+"][data-store="+data+"]").show();
            }            
        });  
        $.each(store, function( index, value ){
            var temp = $("#prod >div[data-store="+value+"]")[0];
            var data = $(temp).attr("data-brand");
            var idx = brand.indexOf(data);
            if(idx > -1){
              $("#prod >div[data-brand="+data+"][data-store="+value+"]").show();
            }            
        });
    }
    else if(brand.length > 0 & !(store.length > 0)){ 
        $.each( brand, function( index, value ){
            $("#prod >div[data-brand="+value+"]").show();
        });
    }
    else if(!(brand.length > 0) & store.length > 0){ 
        $.each( store, function( index, value ){
            $("#prod >div[data-store="+value+"]").show();
        });
    }else{
        $("#prod >div").show();
    }
    }
```

The filtering is working correctly but when i introduce space in strings between checkbox id or in data attribues of divs.
For example,currently in aboave code,there is no space in any checkbox id or any of the data attribute.But going further i have some names with space in between(like brand name-Advance baby)
Now in this case,The check box id will become Advance baby and data-brand attribute will also Be Advance baby.When i give these values and try to filter the divs.Filtering doesnot work.Similarly for store checkbox id and data-store attributes.

Please guide me on above problem as there will be lot of brand and store names with space.
Help me out fr solving this issue..

js fiddle for above code http://jsfiddle.net/qxxL2/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing inverted comma (") in your conditions.. Try this:
it will work:

```
$.each( brand, function( index, value ){
        $("#prod >div[data-brand='"+value+"']").show();
    });
```

And

```
$.each( store, function( index, value ){
        $("#prod >div[data-store='"+value+"']").show();
    });
```